# How to enable and disable a CRM 2011 Organization using C#/VB.Net and WCF Deployment Service or CRM 2011 SDK?

Tags: c#, deployment, crm, dynamics-crm-2011, wcf

I want to be able to enable/disable a CRM 2011 Organization using **Deployment Service (Deployment.Svc)** or **using CRM 2011 SDK** (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Deployment Namespace) using C# or VB.Net application.

I am using some code like this:

```
 Dim StateReq As CRM2011DeploymentSvc.DeleteRequest
                Dim StateResp As CRM2011DeploymentSvc.DeleteResponse

                StateReq.EntityType = DeploymentEntityType.Organization
                StateReq.InstanceTag.Id = FoundOrganization.OrganizationId
                StateReq.InstanceTag.Name = FoundOrganization.UniqueName


                StateResp = CType(_CrmDeployService.Execute(StateReq), DeleteResponse)
```

**1.** Q1: This code is OK as far as deletion of entities(Organization, accounts etc) is concerned. but i am more interested in **Enabling and disabling the organization (occasionally) along deleting (when required)**.

**2.** Q2: Lets say if i Delete an Organization, will i be able to undo delete or recover it. If yes then how and if not what else is the alternative?
**3.** Q3: In CRM 4.0 we can disable/Enable the organization using

```
**SetStateOrganizationRequest**



**SetStateOrganizationResponse**
```

Classes using the Deployment web service but in **CRM 2011**, the Deployment WCF Service does not contain any such method. What should i do to **enable or disable the organization**?

Replies are much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got the solution courtesy of [ResultOnDemand](http://www.resultondemand.nl/support/blog/post/How-to-disable-an-organisation-in-Microsft-CRM-2011-%28MSCRM%29.aspx)

The following code worked for me

```
EntityInstanceId i = new EntityInstanceId();
i.Id = OrganisationId; //Organisation Id

DeploymentService.Organization organization = (DeploymentService.Organization)Provider.deploymentservice.Retrieve(DeploymentEntityType.Organization, i);

//Update status to disabled
organization.State = OrganizationState.Disabled;

DeploymentService.UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
updateRequest.Entity = organization;

//update status
Provider.deploymentservice.Execute(updateRequest);
```